# Getting "Undefined is not an object (evaluating StyleSheet.create)" error in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm new to react-native and i'm trying to use swipe navigation in an app I'm creating. I've installed randomcolor, as well as native-react-swipe but for some reason I'm still getting an error.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper'
import randomcolor from 'randomcolor'

const {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} = React

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  view: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
});

class TitleText extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 48, color: 'white' }}>
        {this.props.label}
      </Text>
    )
  }
}

class Home extends React.Component {

  viewStyle() {
    return {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: randomcolor(),
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper
        loop={false}
        showsPagination={false}
        index={1}>
        <View style={this.viewStyle()}>
          <TitleText label="Left" />
        </View>
        <Swiper
          horizontal={false}
          loop={false}
          showsPagination={false}
          index={1}>
          <View style={this.viewStyle()}>
            <TitleText label="Top" />
          </View>
          <View style={this.viewStyle()}>
            <TitleText label="Home" />
          </View>
          <View style={this.viewStyle()}>
            <TitleText label="Bottom" />
          </View>
        </Swiper>        
        <View style={this.viewStyle()}>
          <TitleText label="Right" />
        </View>
      </Swiper>

    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

The error I'm getting says "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'StyleSheet.create')". I've been trying to crack it for a while now, but haven't had any luck..
That's the code that I have, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to access **React Native** [`components`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.56/components-and-apis) you need to import them from `react-native` and not `react`

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native'
```